# Are there any specific examples of the application of Lewis-Riesenfeld procedure to time dependent Hamiltonians in QM?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, time, schroedinger-equation, adiabatic

[Lewis-Riesenfeld](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=Lewis+Riesenfeld) invariant theory is a theory applicable to solve time-dependent Schrodinger equations. I have always encountered the theory related to the procedure, however never encountered any examples, where it is applied. Please let me know if there are any examples.

Comment: This post (v2) seems like a list question.